# match a list of functions against a list of parameters in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of different polynoms created with np.poly1d:

```
 polys = [p1,p2,...,pn]
```

and I want to know the values that take these polynoms for specific parameters:

```
 xs = [8.1, 2.3, ..., 4.2] #nvalues
```

The results I want is:

```
 ys = [p1(8.1), p2(2.3), ..., pn(4.2)] #I want the numeric values.
```

Comment: feel free to accept an answer if your question is solved - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
[poly(x) for (poly, x) in zip(polys, xs)]
```

I think what you want to do is [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists together, then apply the function in the first list to the value in the second.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `zip` to obtain an iterable of `(function, value)` pairs such that you can call `function(value)`.

Demo:

```
>>> polys = [lambda x: x, lambda x: x**2, lambda x: x**3]
>>> xs = [2, 4, 6]
>>> 
>>> ys = [f(x) for f, x in zip(polys, xs)]
>>> ys
[2, 16, 216]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ys = []
for p, val in zip(polys, xs):
    ys.append(p(val))
```